# Sphinx automodule: class method not documented when decorated with mocked function

Tags: mocking, python-sphinx, python-decorators, class-method, autodoc

I have a class with decorated methods. The function used as a decorator is provided by a module not available when building the documentation, hence this module is mocked in `conf.py` using `autodoc_mock_imports = ['module_with_decorator']`.

```
.. automodule:: my_class
    :members:
```

```
from module_with_decorator import my_decorator


class MyClass:
    """
    My test class.
    """

    @staticmethod
    def my_undecorated_static_method():
        """This is my_undecorated_static_method."""

    @staticmethod
    @my_decorator(param0, param1)
    def my_decorated_static_method():
        """This is my_decorated_static_method."""

    @classmethod
    def my_undecorated_class_method(cls):
        """This is my_undecorated_class_method."""

    @classmethod
    @my_decorator(param0, param1)
    def my_decorated_class_method(cls):
        """This is my_decorated_class_method."""

    def my_undecorated_instance_method(self):
        """This is my_undecorated_instance_method."""

    @my_decorator(param0, param1)
    def my_decorated_instance_method(self):
        """This is my_decorated_instance_method."""
```

The decorated class methods are not shown in the documentation - others are shown correctly.

[image: Missing class method decorated with mocked function]

Any suggestions regarding this issue?

Comment: Is it possible to test if it works if the module with the decorator is available (i.e. not mocked)?

Comment: Yes, it works if the module is available.

Comment: I did not find a solution and could not solve it, so I opened an issue: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/10310